# Regular global sections of invertible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}$
$\newcommand{\ox}{\mathcal{O}_X}$
Let $X$ be a projective scheme of dimension one over a field $k$ and let $\L$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$.

> What are sufficient conditions on $\L$ such that there exists $f \in \L(X)$ with $f\ox \cong \ox$.

**What I have in mind:** There is a bound only depending on $X$ such that $\L$ provides such a nice global section whenever $\deg_k \L := \chi(\L)-\chi(\ox)$ is greater than that bound.

**Note** that if $X$ is *integral* and we embed $\L$ into the constant sheaf $\mathcal{K}_X = K$ where $K$ denotes the *function field* of $X$, then obviously every non-zero global section of $\L$ satisfies the intended condition since it is no zero divisor. Moreover, then we may use Riemann-Roch to deduce the existence of a non-zero section for sufficiently large $\deg_k(\L)$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with $f\ox \cong \ox$? That the induced morphism $\ox\to\mathcal L$ is injective?

Comment: I suppose $f\mathcal{O}_X$ is the ideal sheaf with stalks $f_x\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$; so the condition $f\mathcal{O}_X\cong\mathcal{O}_x$ is equivalent to say that the germs of $f$ are invertible. This is my idea!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that my interpretation of the question is correct, and with the additional assumption that $X$ be Cohen-Macaulay, i.e., has no embedded points, then the answer is *yes*.
By Catanese, Franciosi, Hulek and Reid's *Curve Embedding Theorem*, it is enough that $\mathrm{deg}_B\mathcal L\geq 2p_a(B)+1$ holds for all generically Gorenstein sub-curves $B\subset X$. (This implies that $\mathcal L$ is very ample and very ample line bundles have regular sections.) See Catanese, Franciosi, Hulek, Reid, *Embeddings of Curves and Surfaces*, 1990, Nagoya Math. J. Vol. 154, p. 185-220.

It should be clear that there is no such bound depending only on $\mathrm{deg}_X(\mathcal L)$, though. $\mathcal{L}$ could be trivial on one component and ample on another component, giving positive degree but no section will be regular.

I have no idea what happens in the presence of embedded points.

**Addendum:** As pointed out by the OP, there could be a problem with finite fields. Here is a forceful way out. Let $Z\subset X$ be a $0$-dimensional closed sub-scheme meeting every component of $X$. If $X$ has no embedded points, then if a section is non-trivial at $Z$, then it is non-trivial at all generic points, hence regular. By the Curve embedding Theorem, if $\deg_B\mathcal L\geq 2p_a(B)-1+\mathrm{length}(Z\cap B)$  for all generically Gorenstein sub-curves $B\subset X$, then the restriction map $H^0(\mathcal L)\to H^0(L|_Z)\cong H^0(\mathcal O_Z)$ is surjective. Hence, the pre-image of a nowhere vanishing section is a regular section of $\mathcal L$.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I will have a look at it!

Comment: Could you give me a reference for the statement: If $\mathcal{L}$ is an ample invertible sheaf, then there is $f \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $f\mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: I am still not sure if I really understand $f\mathcal O_X\cong\mathcal O_X$. That’s why I said "every very ample line bundle has a regular section", assuming that this is what you mean.

Comment: Since $f \in \mathcal{L}(X)$, we may define a sheaf $f\mathcal{O}_X$ by defining $(f\mathcal{O}_X)(U) = f_{\mid U} \mathcal{O}_X(U)$. Then $f\mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X$ means that that the maps $s \mapsto s\cdot f_{\mid U}$ are bijective for all open $U \subseteq X$ and $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$. That is locally $f$ always restricts to a non-torsion element.

Comment: Okay, yes, this is the same as saying that the induced morphism $f\colon\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal L$ is injective. But for this, it is enough that $f$ is injective at the associated points of $X$, e.g., by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AV7 and if $X$ has no embedded points, then the associated points are the generic points. But the set of associated points is finite; hence, a general hyper-plane section of the embedding $X\subset\mathbb P^n$ induced by $\mathcal L$ will be non-trivial, hence injective, at the generic points of $X$.

Comment: Ah, but don't we need that $k$ is infinite to argue that we find a hyperplane avoiding the generic (lets say $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay) points of $X$?

Comment: And don't we need that the embedding is a closed immersion and therefore we need to work with a suitable power of $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: "Very ample" means that the map is a closed embedding. But you are right, finite fields cause a problem in this argument.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I just overread the "very" part...

Comment: Dear @windsheaf, I fixed the finite fields issue, but I have to admit, the bound got a lot worse.